# How to initialize bytes with an encoded, string type string

Tags: python

The usual way we create a bytes variable in python is use the following way:

```
b = b'some text i do not care'
```

For example, the chinese character string "鲁邦三世" encode to bytes type is :

```
str_ch = "鲁邦三世"
encoded_str_ch = str_ch.encode("utf-8")
print(encoded_str_ch) # b'\xe9\xb2\x81\xe9\x82\xa6\xe4\xb8\x89\xe4\xb8\x96'
```

now if i have a string:

```
s = '\xe9\xb2\x81\xe9\x82\xa6\xe4\xb8\x89\xe4\xb8\x96' 
# same with encoded_str_ch, but it's string type
```

how can i initialize a bytes variable just use the variable s, not the encoded string '\xe9...\x96'

i tried

```
bytes(str_ch, encoding = "utf8")
```

but it's not correct, still got the same result with s

or there is not a way to do this...

Answer (score 2):

So you have a Unicode string, but the code points are really UTF-8 bytes?  That generally means the string was decoded with the wrong codec. The following translates code points back to bytes, since  `latin1` is the first 256 code points and maps 1:1 back to bytes:

```
b = s.encode('latin1')
```